# How to restart page numbering in Word Document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I have a Word Document with page munbering starting from second page. And its look like:

```
first page - <no number>
second page - 3
third page -4
etc...
```

Now i want to restart page numbering to:

```
first page - <no number>
second page - 6
third page -7
etc...
```

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947301/restart-page-numbering-in-header-with-openxml-sdk-2-0)

I mean i just put a new `Paragraph` into my document. It's work but MS Word opened document with errors.

After i tried put a new `Paragraph` in `Footer`:

```
string headerID = @"{ PAGE \* MERGEFORMAT }";
var footer = mainPart.FooterParts.First().Footer;
var paragraphtest = new Paragraph(
    new ParagraphProperties(
        new SectionProperties(
            new FooterReference {Id = headerID},
            new PageNumberType {Start = 10}
         )
     )
 );
footer.Append(paragraphtest);
```

But now document just not opened.
How correctly restart a page numbering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh sorry guys it was a stupid question. Ten minutes later i found solution. Just needed take a first `SectionProperties` element in document and set a page numbering start value:

```
var firstSection=  mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>().First();
firstSection.Append(new PageNumberType { Start = 10 });
```